# Science Fiction Fantasy about earth in the far future covered by a jungle that is miles thick

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Pre 80s story where earth is covered by a sentient jungle and there is only one human woman whom the jungle entity protects. The jungle covers the entire world and is a few miles thick from top to bottom. When the woman becomes lonely the entity finds a man buried away in some long forgotten cryo pod and awakes him to be the woman's mate. Unfortunately the man dies before he can meet the woman - the jungle is harsh and full of deadly creatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Earthchild by Doris Piserchia**

I actually just read this!  :-)

The book is from 1977. From the back cover:

> She called herself Reee and she was the last human being on Earth. This was the one thing she was sure of. Because Earth was not a dead planet, not by a long way. There were all manner of strange plants and bizarre animals, and there were the blue boys who insisted they were human--but she always set fire to them. There was however Indigo, the all-devouring protoplasmic ocean that was literally gobbling up everything in the world. And there was the enigmatic Emeroo to whom she owed her continued existence. There were also the so-called Martians - humans who had fled to Mars and only came back to Earth to scout for survivors and vent their futile furies on the the inhospitable homeworld.

The scene you mention about he man in a cryopod I think is a mixup of several scenes. Early on, Reee spots a Martian helicopter crashing and finds the man who survived the crash. Later, the entity helping her, Emeroo, finds a young Martian man that Reee might hook up with, and later on more possible match-ups, but something always goes wrong: The men don't believe her, don't respect her, want her to be subservient or follow foolish traditions, etc.

[image]

Comment: PERFECT - this is the story! Thank you. There are so many sci fi books I read in my early teens that I want to re-read but I can't remember the name or who wrote them.

Comment: @DareBehr: please accept the answer to close the question. 